# deleting /MDd 's DLL memory from /MD Exe file causes heap corruption

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I want to delete exe's allocated memory from dll.

when I test..

1. Exe : /MD , DLL : /MDd => HeapCorruption.
2. Exe : /MD , DLL : /MD  => work's well, as long as when I see.

even LocalAlloc makes same result...

as long as I know, multi-thread-dll crt is using same heap memory.
could you tell me why the case 1 test is always heap corrupt ?

and, How Can I fix this?.

-- addition.
ofcourse It is best, restricting allocation / deallcation in same place.

but my prob is.. 
the size is first visible from exe file, but dll needs to using the memory by output parameter.
- querying size / then getting buffer is not that I want (too complicate, for dll user.)

Comment: Are you mixing debug and release? `/MDd` is used for debug. `/MD` for release. If you mix debug and release you will likely corrupt the heap since the debug heap is incompatible with the release heap.

Comment: The debug CRT uses a different allocator, it provides better diagnostics.  VS versions before 2012 created their own heap.  So sure, this is all supposed to not work well.  You do have the goody that avoids these problems strongly, you can create a solution in VS that has both projects.  Which trivially lets you build and test these projects with their settings in sync, easy peasy.  Not taking advantage of it is a big mistake.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to delete exe's allocated memory from dll.

That's not a good idea. It's better to leave the code memory allocation and the corresponding deallocation in either the EXE or the DLL.

Even if the EXE and the DLL are both of the same build type (debug/release), you should not deallocate memory in one when it is allocated in the other.

If you allocate and deallocate memory in the same unit, i.e. the EXE or the DLL, you should be able to mix debug and non-debug versions without running into the memory corruption issue.

Comment: Or use an allocation pair like CoTaskMemAlloc/CoTaskMemFree that is specifically intended for cross-module use.